# T Test Analysis Question

Tags: machine-learning, t-test

I’m submitting this post in hopes of receiving feedback regarding a project that I’m working on. I need a sanity check to ensure that there isn’t a blatant flaw in my logic that I’m overlooking.

**Overview of the problem:**

I am trying to identify the highest valued actions a customer can take during their life cycle. This specific scenario takes place in the restaurant industry.

The output I’m working towards is applying a monetary value to actions a customer could take during a particular ‘event’. An event could be the customers first transaction, and in this example, I want to identify the three highest value actions a customer can take during this event. As for an action, this could be anything that a customer has control over when engaging with the company (e.g. the day of the week they visited, what specific products they ordered, which location they went to, etc.).

The first approach I took to solve this problem was training numerous classifier model which would classify whether a customer would be a low or high value customer. From this classifier, I built another model which would extract individual feature importance value (e.g. what day of the week was most important in predicting a low versus high value customer). Long story short, it worked, kind of, but it was heavily convoluted and difficult to convey to stakeholders.

**Current solution:**

When I went to test the validity of the output that I produced from my initial model attempt, I realized that there might be an incredibly elegant and explanatory solution to this problem.

What I have done is built an algorithm to process simple hypothesis tests (via two sample, two tailed t-tests) on every possible action a customer can decide to make on their first transaction (e.g. the day of the week they visited, what specific products they ordered, which location they went to, etc.).

**Here’s a sample experiment/hypothesis:**

- Population: Any person who made their first transaction within the last 365 days
- Group A: All customers who did purchase an alcoholic beverage on their first transaction
- Group B: All customers who did not purchase an alcoholic beverage product on their first transaction
- H0: u total amount spent over Group A’s life cycle == u total amount spent over Group B’s life cycle
- Ha: u total amount spent over Group A’s life cycle != u total amount spent over Group B’s life cycle

**Results:**

- p-value: 0.0000001
- Average total amount spent in Group A’s life cycle: $500
- Average total amount spent in Group B’s life cycle: $200
- Value added: $300
- +/-: $50
- Conclusion: At a confidence level of 99%, there is enough evidence to claim that customer who purchase an alcoholic beverage on their first transaction produce a higher average total amount spent over their life cycle than those who do not purchase an alcoholic beverage

I processed this hypothesis for every single individual action possible for a customer to take. The hypothesis tests consider nothing different between the groups other than whether or not the specific action was taken by the customer.

**Here’s the question:**

Am I interpreting these results incorrectly? Is there something I’m missing?

I know that this doesn't suggest that only the purchase of an acholic beverage on the first transaction is the reason for the additional value added, but I do think this suggests that if someone does purchase an acholic beverage on the first transaction that 99% of the time their average total spend over their life cycle will be $200 (+/- 50) more than someone who doesn't.

This seems too good and simple to be true, but I can’t find a hole in this approach. Per the sample hypothesis I provided above, is it wrong to conclude (in consideration to only a raw total amount spent metric) that customers who purchase an alcoholic beverage on their first transaction will, on average, spend more than a customer who doesn’t?

I appreciate any feedback / review of this submission. Thanks!